# Redux - Define new state in reducer switch statement with new variable each time?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

My reducer looks like this:

```
switch (action.type) {
      case "UPDATE_CURRENT_USER":
        let newState = {...state, ...action.payload };
        return newState;
      case "GET_CURRENT_USER":
        return state;
      case "UPDATE_USERNAME":
        newState = {...state, name: action.payload.name};
        return state;
  }
```

Now, the second time I am using `newState` I am not defining it again. I am simply using the variable I have defined above. Is this ok?
I wanted to define it anew, but got an error. But I am not sure whether this way will still give me the correct result - although everything seems to be working fine?

Comment: Do not declare a varibale in a case statement you want to use it somewhere else as well, do it outside the switch statement

Answer (score 5):

Use curly braces `{}` to create new block scope inside of the case statement:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "UPDATE_CURRENT_USER": {
    let newState = {...state, ...action.payload };
    return newState;
  }
  case "GET_CURRENT_USER":
    return state;
  case "UPDATE_USERNAME": {
    let newState = {...state, name: action.payload.name};
    return newState;
  }
}
```

Since `let` and `const` are block scoped local variables, they are visible only in the current block.

I your code you are using undeclared `newState` variable:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "UPDATE_CURRENT_USER":
    // (conditionaly) declaring block scoped variable newState
    let newState = {...state, ...action.payload };
    return newState;
  case "UPDATE_USERNAME":
    // here you cannot declare newState variable because it might be declared before
    // however the variable is not declared since we are in other case
    // so that here you are using global window variable window.newState
    newState = {...state, name: action.payload.name};
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain why I should do this, and where my current  code may go wrong / should be avoided?

Comment: In general it works, but I would not use this approach because it is unusual practice for reducers, especially for such easy use case.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a variable for new state, assign a value to it and return it. Instead, you can return the new state value right away. And also do not forget to add a default case at the end.

```
switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_CURRENT_USER':
          return { ...state, ...action.payload };
        case 'GET_CURRENT_USER':
          return state;
        case 'UPDATE_USERNAME':
          return { ...state, name: action.payload.name };
        default:
          return state;
      }
```